# getting object is not subscriptable in MySQL connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I have a python program in which i want to update details using mysqlconnector in my data base but i am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\devided github\repo_data.py", line 116, in <module>
    getRepos()
  File "d:\devided github\repo_data.py", line 101, in getRepos
    for repo in cursor:
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 718, in fetchone
    return self._fetch_row()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 689, in _fetch_row
    row = self._rows[self._next_row]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

my code

```
def getRepos():
    cursor.execute("select repo_name,github_id from user_repo WHERE Processed = 'N'")
    
    for repo in cursor:
        username = repo[1]
        repo_name = repo[0]
        total_commit = total_commit_fetch_web_scrap(repo_name, username)
        total_commit_user = total_commit_user_func(repo_name, username)
        total_contributors = total_contributors_func(repo_name, username)
        language_dict = {}
        fetch_language(username, repo_name, language_dict)
        
        sql = 'UPDATE user_repo SET contributors=%s, total_commits=%s, commit_by_user=%s, language_1=%s, language_2=%s, language_3=%s, language_4=%s, language_5=%s, language_6=%s, language_7=%s WHERE repo_name=%s AND github_id=%s;'
        val = (total_contributors, total_commit, total_commit_user, language_dict['languages1'], language_dict['languages2'], language_dict['languages3'], language_dict['languages4'], language_dict['languages5'], language_dict['languages6'], language_dict['languages7'], repo_name, username)
        cursor.execute(sql,val)
    connection.commit()
```

cursor is

```
cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
```

Comment: Can you share the content of the variable "sql"? Try to print it before executing, you will probably see then what is wrong.

Comment: @Culme i have updated the question I have formatted the query now i am getting different error please check.

Comment: If you just do print(sql) before trying to execute the sql, it might still help a lot. It could be missing quotes or something, much easier to tell if you share the full value of "sql".

Comment: @Culme print looks fine to me.

Comment: @Culme there is some error in ```cursor.execute``` because i tried to remove it and then run and it worked i was not getting error but  ```cursor.execute``` is important for database so i cannot remove it. what should i do any suggestions.

Comment: The error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" is a python error from what I can see. Google that exact phrase and you will probably find some useful info. (Not trying to be sarcastic, just seeing that this does not relate to the original question so you might need to kind of start over with the troubleshooting.)